# ArrayAdapter initialization error (Android)

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have written the following code snippet in my App:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            LP_Events_Tab mEventsTab= new LP_Events_Tab();
            mList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.event_list);
            String[] temp= {"1","2","3"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp);
            return mEventsTab;

           /*Other cases*/
    }
    return null;
}
```

For case 0, I am using an array of strings named `temp` to initialize the `ArrayAdapter`. However, Android Studio redlines the `ArrayAdapter` initialization arguments: `(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp)` and thus, I cannot proceed. I do not see any error with these arguments but Android Studio does and hence, I am stuck.

Comment: If this is inside the Fragment, you should use `getContext()` instead of `this` keyword.

Comment: That could be the reason you are getting redline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following line of code inside your Fragment -

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, temp);
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Constructor of Adapter

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
```

So make sure you are passing right parameters, in your case your first parameter is `this` which will not work other then in Activity.
So pass either `getContext` or `getActivity`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace "this" with "MainActivity.this"(or whatever class name you have)

Comment: don't you think it will be the wrong answer if he is using fragment, not Activity?

Comment: There are cases when this works, it depends on the situation. If he wants, he will try and see if my answer suits his needs. Otherwise, he will choose another answer ;)

Comment: dont get angry bro .. i am just trying to help....what you said is true in case of anonymous classes then one has to use  "this" with "MainActivity.this" but he is not using anonymous classes thats why this could be wrong answer